# Can I omit the full path of a "shebang" on the first line of shell script?

Tags: linux, bash

I often see `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the first line of shell scripts.

It seems to work fine to omit `/usr/bin/` part on macos:

```sh
#!env bash

echo Yo
```

Can I do that on all other Unix-like platforms?

Comment: A simple `#! env bash` does not work for me in Ubuntu 18.04 with bash 4.4.19 whereas `#! /usr/bin/env bash` works.

Comment: I would expect the shebang to require a full path; if `PATH` lookups were performed on the name, there would be no need to use `env` in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using interpreter without full path is not supported everywhere. In many cases, kernel does the shebang handling and kernel normally does not know about the environment variables, including PATH. So it needs a full path in order to find the interpreter.

That's why `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is used - `bash` is located and executed by `env`, so it allows `bash` to be anywhere in PATH, while only requiring `/usr/bin/env` to be in known location. You can't use just `#!bash` or `#!env bash`, because kernel does not know, where to find them.

Using plain interpreter may work sometimes - it means that shebang handling is done by something that is aware of the environment, most likely by the active shell itself and not by the kernel.

There are good answers about the similar question also available:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77512/why-not-use-pathless-shebangs
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my